# Django REST Framework: Get ID/URL during validation?

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have a `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`. To implement its `validate` method properly, I need to access the *primary key* or *the URL* of the object that is being validated – if it has one, i.e. if it's being *edited*, not created. What's the correct way of doing that?

I tried many things, but the only approach that worked was a hack that fetches the ID of the object when the serializer is instantiated into it's `id` field:

```
class BoxSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Box
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'url')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BoxSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.id = None \
            if len(args) != 1 or not isinstance(args[0], Box) \
            else args[0].id

    def validate(self, data):
        print(data)
        return data
```

What's the proper way to access the ID/URL of the object being validated from within the serializer's `validate` method? Neither `data['id']` nor `data['url']` exist.

---

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.BoxDetail.as_view(), name='box-detail'),
]
```

`views.py`:

```
class BoxDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Box.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BoxSerializer
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You can access the `id` of the object being edited by `self.instance`.**

From the DRF serializers docs on [Accessing the initial data and instance:](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#accessing-the-initial-data-and-instance)

> When passing an initial object or queryset to a serializer instance,
>   the object will be made available as `.instance`. If no initial object
>   is passed then the `.instance` attribute will be `None`.

Since you are using `HyperLinkedModelSerializer`, you will have access to the object being edited in case of `PUT` requests as an `instance` attribute set on the serializer. You can use this `instance` attribute to access the `id` of the object being edited by doing `self.instance.id`.

You can write your validation logic in `validate()` function then after getting the object id in the variable `object_id`. This will not affect create requests as `instance` will not be set on the serializer then.

```
class BoxSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Box
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'url')

    def validate(self, data):
        if self.instance: # 'instance' will be set in case of `PUT` request i.e update
            object_id = self.instance.id # get the 'id' for the instance
            # write your validation logic based on the object id here

        return data
```

**Another way** to access the object id is by accessing the `kwargs` from the `view` object in the serializer `context` dictionary.

```
my_view = self.context['view'] # get the 'view' object from serializer context
object_id = my_view.kwargs.get('pk') # access the 'view' kwargs and lookup for 'pk'
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: Where do you know that from? Does the documentation say this *anywhere*? I could swear I read the whole documentation *twice* searching for this.

Comment: I faced a similar issue and then had to look into the source code of DRF to understand if the object is being set as a variable to the serializer. Also there is a slight mention in the DRF serializer docs about this. I have updated the ans with that page link. I think checking out the source code also of DRF along with the documentation helps better. :)

Comment: self.instance get all values that we need !

Answer (score 0):

Call the serializer with the `context` attribute.

```
serializer = BoxSerializer(queryset, context={'request': self.request}, ...)
```

Now you can access the `request` object from the `validate` function with

```
self.context['request']['id']
```

Comment: I'm using a `generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` with `serializer_class=MySerializer` directive, but `self.context['request']['id']` from within of the serializer's `validate` method gives me a `TypeError`: *"'Request' object is not subscriptable"*

Comment: In your case you have to overwrite the `get_serializer_class()` method.

Comment: On a side note, an object is subscriptable  if it implements the `__getitem__()` function (egs are lists, tuples, dictionaries and strings). `request` object being not a dictionary we can't access a variable using `['id']`.We need to use the `.` operator.  Also `id`  will not be present as an attribute on `request` object.